# Vectorized Method instead of using for loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 'tmp' on which I need to do perform calculation using the last row of another dataframe 'SpreadData'. I am using following code:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(tmp)){for(j in 1:nrow(tmp)){PNLData[j,i] = 10*tmp[j,i]*SpreadData[nrow(SpreadData),i]}}
```

Is there any faster method using mapply or something else so that I need not to use for loop.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `outer`  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sweep()`:

```
PNLData <- sweep(10 * tmp, 2, SpreadData[nrow(SpreadData), ], "*")
```

PS1: you can replace `SpreadData[nrow(SpreadData), ]` by `tail(SpreadData, 1)`.

PS2: I think this makes two copies of your data. If you have a large matrix, you'd better use Rcpp.

**Edit:** Rcpp solution: put that an .cpp file and source it.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix rcppFun(const NumericMatrix& x,
                      const NumericVector& lastCol) {

  int n = x.nrow();
  int m = x.ncol();

  NumericMatrix res(n, m);
  int i, j;

  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      res(i, j) = 10 * x(i, j) * lastCol[j];
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

And do in R `PNLData <- rcppFun(tmp, SpreadData[nrow(SpreadData), ])`.

Comment: Thanks Prive. I actually do have a large matrix. Can you please help me out with RCpp. How to do it using RCpp?

Comment: Also one with the 'sweep' gives the following error:  Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator. Any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: I solved the error as: PNLData2 = sweep(10 * tmp, 2, as.numeric(SpreadData[nrow(SpreadData), ]), "*"). But however, can you please help me out with Rcpp?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Tell me if it works (as we have no reproducible example to check my ourselves).

Comment: @Prive: Sure. Although, 'sweep' is also fast enough in my case. I give Rcpp also a try.

Comment: @Garv If you are happy with the answer, please validate it.

Comment: @Prive Done. Thanks again!!